# What's the Maclaurin series of $\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions, harmonic-numbers

I am trying to find a closed-form for the Maclaurin series of $\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}$. I am not sure if it's possible but here is what I did:

We know that:

$$\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_n-H_{2n}}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)x^{2n}\tag1$$

$$\frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}$$

And by the Cauchy product of power series

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nx^n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\ b_{n-k+1}\right)$$

we have

$$\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\left(\frac{H_k-H_{2k}}{k}-\frac1{2k^2}\right)\right)},$$

and I have no idea how to deal with the blue sum, any idea? Or maybe a different approach?

---

The identity of $(1)$ can be found in the book *Almost Impossible Integrals, Sums and Series*.

Comment: You may already have considered this, but I would try writing out one of the blue sums, say for $n = 5$, term by term, expanding $H_k$ by its definition as well, and seeing what cancellations occur. My suspicion is that few terms will remain after doing this. Or at least, the terms that remain will be easy to write a simple formula for.

Comment: thats a good idea but lets say we get some cancellation, it wont be easy to see the pattern after cancellation.

Comment: For a less brute force approach, there may be some well known formulas for the sum of the first term in the blue sum.

Comment: How did you get $x^{2n-1}$?  It seems obvious from your earlier statements that we only want the even powers

Comment: @Henry ah you right .. I made a mistake its edited now. Thanks though.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDkH8.png